# Git tree-filter discards changes again in consecutive commits

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

We plan on enforcing a clang-format based style in a source repository. We anticipate some difficulties, which is why we want to provide a make target to perform re-formatting for the current branch from its merge base with master to the branch HEAD.

As a simplified example, consider the following command:

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter '
  AFFECTED_FILES=$(git diff-index --diff-filter=AM --name-only $GIT_COMMIT^);
  echo; echo AFFECTED $AFFECTED_FILES;
  for f in $AFFECTED_FILES; do
    echo formatting $f;
    echo foo >> $f;
  done
' HEAD~10..HEAD
```

We run a tree-filter on a number of commits (we simply limit this to the last few commits, this already demonstrates the problem). We determine the affected files (we only want to touch files added or modified in the commit). For simplicity (the error is easier to spot), we do not use clang-format here, but simply append "foo" to each of these affected files (replacing `echo foo >> $f` with `clang-format -i $f` is all that is needed to get the actual code).

It does properly apply the changes we intend. However, in each but the first commit, it discards the changes we made previously. Looking through the commits, assume in a file some.txt you see "+foo" in the diff. In the child commit, for some.txt you see "-foo" in the diff, even if some.txt was not modified in the child commit at all, but only someother.txt. I have run this on arbitrary test repos, showing the same behavior.

I have also tried the following (coming back to actual clang-format):

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'git clang-format --extensions cpp,h' -- HEAD~10..HEAD
```

While most commits do look correct, the first one will modify all files touched by any commit in the given range. I want to avoid this and only format the files touched by a commit anyway.

What am I missing to avoid undoing the changes in child commits? Do I need to update the index in some way?

Comment: You could add your solution as an answer to your own question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tree filter in `git filter-branch` looks at the state of the files at each commit, but changing those files in one commit has no effect on the state of the files in the next commit that the tree filter looks at. This means that if you make some changes to only one commit in a `git filter-branch` invocation, then those changes will not be propogated on to the children of that commit. This means that the *tree* of the those children will be unchanged when compared to the pre-rewritten commit and will, therefore, appear to undo the custom changes introduced in their rewritten parent.

To achieve what you want, you will probably want to consider a different set of `AFFECTED_FILES`, such doing a `diff` against `HEAD~10` instead of just the parent commit to make sure that any file that was previously rewritten still gets reformatted. (Note that this isn't perfect, because if a file gets reverted to the exact state that it was at in `HEAD~10` then it will start being omitted from reformatting again, but this may be an edge case which is rare enough that it isn't worth coding around - or you could include diffs against all parents *and* the base of the `filter-branch` operation.)

Comment: Or—much simpler, though more computationally expensive—just run everything through clang-format in every commit. Of course the OP ruled that one out generally, but if applied to the entire repository going back to the beginning of time, it need only be done once...

Comment: @torek: Agreed, this approach is a more natural fit for what `filter-branch` does - and is good at.

Comment: Thanks @CBBailey. This does, indeed, fix the reversions in the successor commits. However, it also means that the process can slow down considerably for branches which modify an increasing number of files. A lot of formatting work is repeated. Is there a way to access the "new parent" commit hash? Then, I could simply checkout previous files without running another re-format (unless the file is affected directly in the current commit, then I would re-format anyway).

Comment: @timn: I believe the `map` shell function is available in a `tree-filter`, it definitely is within a `commit-filter`. If you are after speed, you should consider using an `index-filter`; this doesn't give you files on disk, but if you can use your filter in something like a `git cat-file blob :name-in-index | filter-cmd | git hash-object -w --stdin` you can use the output object id in a `git update-index` invocation. As an optimisation you could teach your filter command to keep an offline cache of old object id to new object id so that each identical in put is only processed once.

Comment: Thanks again! `map` did the trick. See the solution I added to the question and links to the actual implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @CBBailey for the quick and useful replies. With these bits of information, I came up with the following solution:

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'echo;
  PREV=$(map $(git rev-parse $GIT_COMMIT^));
  echo PREV $PREV;
  AFFECTED_FILES=$(git diff --name-only $GIT_COMMIT^..$GIT_COMMIT | egrep "\.(h|cpp)$");
  echo AFFECTED $AFFECTED_FILES;
  PREV_AFFECTED_FILES=$(bash -c "comm -23 <(git diff --name-only HEAD~10..$GIT_COMMIT^ | egrep \"\.(h|cpp)$\" | sort -u) <(echo $AFFECTED_FILES | sort -u)");
  echo PREV_AFFECTED $PREV_AFFECTED_FILES;
  for f in $PREV_AFFECTED_FILES; do
    echo "checking out $f";
    git checkout $PREV -- $f;
  done;
  for f in $AFFECTED_FILES; do
    echo formatting $f;
    clang-format -i $f;
  done
' -- HEAD~10..HEAD
```

In addition to the files affected by the commits, it also determines all files which have been affected in the given commit range before the current commit (PREV_AFFECTED_FILES). These are filtered for files which have also been touched by the current commit (we need to run this in bash, as sh, which is used by filter-branch, does not support process substitution using `<()`). We use the map function which is defined by filter-branch (cf. last paragraph in the Filters section of the [filter-branch documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_filters)) to determine the rewritten predecessor commit (PREV). All previously affected files are then checked out from this commit (which is why we need to filter PREV_AFFECTED_FILES to not contain any from AFFECTED_FILES, we would otherwise overwrite our changes). The files affected in the current commit are then formatted. Using index-filter might still be faster. However, with the given constraints to reformat only modified files and checkout previously modified files this is fast enough for our use-case.

You can see the final version in our buildsystem ([script](https://github.com/fawkesrobotics/fawkes/blob/a6175d3558d364bb6508547032a7c64f4030d291/etc/buildsys/root/format-tree-filter.sh), [invocation](https://github.com/fawkesrobotics/fawkes/blob/a6175d3558d364bb6508547032a7c64f4030d291/etc/buildsys/root/format.mk#L71-L86)). It contains further improvements, e.g., using [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to speed up formatting files.